# How to rename a table in Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

probably a very trivial question but I'm not sure about this and also don't want to lose the table. How do I rename a table in Athena?

```
Database name - friends
table name - centralPark
desired table name -centralPerk
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can't!

see the [list of unsupported DDL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/unsupported-ddl.html) in Athena.

what you can do is to make a new table [using select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table-as.html#ctas-table-examples):

```
CREATE TABLE centralPark
AS SELECT * FROM centralPerk
WITH DATA
```

and drop the old table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS centralPerk
```

Comment: What is with data?

Comment: @DawsonSmith to bring data in that table to the new table  if you have any. you can use '`with no data` , so only you make the empty table

Comment: Can you help me with a new question I posted?

Comment: Works but if the table is partitoned it doesn't keep the partitions, any idea for this?

Comment: @dduque you have to create table with  option `WITH partitioned_by = ARRAY[ col_name[,…] ]` and then list the column names in the select statement that the partition(s) is based on . See docs  for `using select` in my answer

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was accepted.
This might be VERY long, VERY expensive, might fail, and eventually you might get table with wrong structure.
This command creates new Parquet table with a single partition with the data copied from original. If originally you had 50TB table with 2000 partitions this will probably fail, or create inefficient table.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but for new people that seek the answer I'll write anyway.

There's no single command but you can do it easily with 2, either manually or programatically.
You do

```
show create table `your_table`
```

Then copy-paste the "create external table" command to the editor, replace table name and run.

If the table includes non-projection partitions, you will also need to run this to detect and load your partitions.

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE `your_table`
```

You can do the same programmatically by doing simple regexp replace of the table name and rerun. It's more complicated of course than running "CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ..." but it's immediate, free and will promise the same structure pointing to the same place in S3.

Answer (score 0):

Using a CTAS query is effective, but I found it to be quite slow. It needs to copy all the files.

But *you* don't need to copy the files. You can create a new table directly in the Glue catalog and point it at the existing files. This works in seconds or less.

If you're using Python, I highly recommend the [awswrangler](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library for this kind of work.

```py
import awswrangler as wr

def wrangler_copy(db, old_name, new_name):
    wr.catalog.create_parquet_table(
        db,
        new_name,
        path=wr.catalog.get_table_location(db, old_name),
        columns_types=wr.catalog.get_table_types(db, old_name),
        # TODO: partitions, etc
    )
```

And then drop the old table if you like.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS <old_name>
```